# Loading custom cell value from array depending on users choice in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have an uitableview with custom cell. Custom cell contains a label and two buttons. 
For each object (label, uibuttons) I'm loading a separate value from three separate arrays.

```
Label = [which fruit do you prefer?, Apple which color?, Orange which color?,    
orange which price?, Apple which price?]
Uibutton1 = [apple, green, deep orange, 5.99, 4.99]
Uibutton2 = [orange, red, yellow, 2.99, 1.99]
```

My goal is to load the first value for all three objects into cell and then append the cell values depending on users choice.

For instance, if the first question is
Which fruit do you prefer?

And user replies oranges the cell with third object (for uilabel and two uibuttons) is loaded, which would result in

Orange which color?

Deep orange 
Yellow

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an enum and computed properties:

```
enum Question {
    case WhichFruit, AppleColor, OrangeColor, ApplePrice, OrangePrice
}
var currentQuestion: Question = .WhichFruit {
    didSet { updateTitles() }
}

var questionText: String {
    switch currentQuestion {
    case .WhichFruit: return "Which fruit do you prefer?"
    case .AppleColor, .OrangeColor: return "Which color?"
    case .ApplePrice, .OrangePrice: return "Which price?"
    }
}
var button1Text: String {
    switch currentQuestion {
    case .WhichFruit: return "Apple"
    case .AppleColor: return "Green"
    case .OrangeColor: return "Deep Orange"
    case .OrangePrice: return "5.99"
    case .ApplePrice: return "4.99"
    }
}
//continue for button2
//...
```

Then, to load initial data:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    currentQueston = .WhichFruit
}
private func updateTitles() {
    questionLabel.text = questionText
    buttonOne.setTitle(button1Text, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonTwo.setTitle(button2Text, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

And then in the button actions, update the currentQuestion and call updateTitles once again.

```
func buttonOneWasPressed {
    switch currentQuestion {
    case .WhichFruit: //selected Apple
        currentQuestion = .AppleColor
    }
    //other cases here
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try out the code. The first thing that comes to mind - what if i have much more options in all of the arrays? do i have to write cases every single time?

Comment: If you're planning on using the exact same labels and buttons, then yes you would. That being said, by designing it this way it should not be too much effort to add in new options. Also, if this solution ends up suiting your needs, please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, you could use a didSet in currentQuestion to always call update. `var currentQuestion: Question = .WhichFruit { didSet {updateTitles()} }` -- see the revised answer